# Could not load the backend plugin In Python Cura Application

Tags: python, installation

Here I did proper setup as per its documentation from this link and application build also succeeds but after build the application software crashes and shows me crash report as below please give me some solution

I cloned the project from this link Cura(Python): https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura.git

```
**Error Traceback**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Cura\cura_app.py", line 239, in <module>`
      app.run()
  File "D:\Cura\cura\CuraApplication.py", line 829, in run
super().run()
  File "D:\Uranium\UM\Qt\QtApplication.py", line 381, in run
      super().run()
  File "D:\Uranium\UM\Application.py", line 268, in run
     self.startSplashWindowPhase()
 File "D:\Cura\cura\CuraApplication.py", line 497, in startSplashWindowPhase
super().startSplashWindowPhase()
File "D:\Uranium\UM\Qt\QtApplication.py", line 235, in startSplashWindowPhase
self._loadPlugins()
File "D:\Cura\cura\CuraApplication.py", line 813, in _loadPlugins
raise RuntimeError("Could not load the backend plugin!")
RuntimeError: Could not load the backend plugin!


**Logs**

Thread 0x00001dc4 (most recent call first):
```

`File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApp \PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 472 in acquire File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 98 in _nextJob File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 124 in run File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038 in _bootstrap_inner File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 995 in _bootstrap`

```
Thread 0x0000138c (most recent call first):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 472 in acquire
File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 98 in _nextJob
File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 124 in run
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 995 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000012a8 (most recent call first):
 File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 472 in acquire
File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 98 in _nextJob
File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 124 in run
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 995 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00000e00 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 472 in acquire
File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 98 in _nextJob
File "D:\Uranium\UM\JobQueue.py", line 124 in run
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038 in _bootstrap_inner
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 995 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x000023e4 (most recent call first):
File "D:\Cura\cura\CrashHandler.py", line 397 in _logInfoWidget
File "D:\Cura\cura\CrashHandler.py", line 182 in _createDialog
```

i am tried all possible ways given from community